# Error while executing shell commands from GroovyConsole

Tags: groovy, createprocess, groovy-console

I downloaded apache-groovy-2.4.6 for windows and from the GroovyConsole when i try to execute "dir".execute(), I am getting

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can you tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have "dir" as a runnable program. It is a [built-in function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Built-in_commands) in `cmd`.

Try

```
println  "cmd /c dir   c:\\".execute().text
```